# Baikal and Carddav Android 20:not a directory

Tags: nginx, webdav

I installed Baikal 0.4.5 to my new Debian server with Nginx and PHP 5.6. Past installations of Baikal completed without any problems. Unfortunately now I can't connect with Carddav on Android (https://example.com:443/baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default). The generated errors assume that a directory is missing?

For your info, the web interface is working well. By visiting https://example.com/baikal/html/admin/ I'm be able to login. At /baikal/html/card.php the same.

Acces:

```
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/ HTTP/1.1" 207 312 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/ HTTP/1.1" 207 266 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /.well-known/carddav HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php HTTP/1.1" 401 1806 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - username [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php HTTP/1.1" 207 615 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/ HTTP/1.1" 207 306 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/ HTTP/1.1" 207 312 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
my_ip - - [06/Aug/2016:16:27:16 +0200] "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/ HTTP/1.1" 207 312 "-" "CardDAV-Sync free/0.4.20.1 (Telephone; Tel_type; Android 5.1.1; Lang; org.dmfs.carddav.sync/141)"
```

Errors:

```
2016/08/06 16:27:16 [alert] 28415#0: *22 dav_ext stat failed on '/var/www/example.com/web/baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/' (20: Not a directory), client: 85.144.105.229, server: example.com, request: "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com:443"
2016/08/06 16:27:16 [alert] 28415#0: *22 dav_ext stat failed on '/var/www/example.com/web/baikal/html/dav.php/' (20: Not a directory), client: 85.144.105.229, server: example.com, request: "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com:443"
2016/08/06 16:27:16 [alert] 28415#0: *23 dav_ext stat failed on '/var/www/example.com/web/baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/' (20: Not a directory), client: 85.144.105.229, server: example.com, request: "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2016/08/06 16:27:16 [alert] 28415#0: *26 dav_ext stat failed on '/var/www/example.com/web/baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/' (20: Not a directory), client: 85.144.105.229, server: example.com, request: "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com:443"
2016/08/06 16:27:16 [alert] 28415#0: *26 dav_ext stat failed on '/var/www/example.com/web/baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/' (20: Not a directory), client: 85.144.105.229, server: example.com, request: "PROPFIND /baikal/html/dav.php/principals/username/default/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com:443"
```

Configuration of Baikal in vhost:

```
rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /baikal/html/dav.php redirect;
rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /baikal/html/dav.php redirect;

dav_methods     PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing the configuration required for Baikal friendly URL to work. You need to check what is the URL rewriting required on the webserver to make it work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It led to the solution for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Tero Kilkanen](https://serverfault.com/users/210570/tero-kilkanen) I was able to solve the problem. It was just a problem in the file configuration. The old situation:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

The new and working situation:

```
location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```